# pie chart using googlechart api with json data coming from django view

Tags: python, django, google-visualization

I am trying to create a pie chart using google chart api. And data for the chart I want to get from django **views**. I used the code bellow but I not getting any chart.

views.py

```
def demo_piechart(request):
    rRows = Verification.objects.filter(status=1).count()
    vRows = Verification.objects.filter(status=2).count()
    tRows = Verification.objects.filter(status=3).count()
    print rRows,vRows,tRows
    data={'values': [['Verified', vRows], ['Tampered', tRows], ['Registered', rRows]]}
    return render_to_response('piechart.html',data
```

)

pichart.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var djangoData = {{ data|safe }};
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoData);

        var options = {
          title: 'Chart Title'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Any solution...**

Comment: Open the page in a browser and view the source - what is output by `{{ data|safe }}`?

Comment: It seems there is missing header row something like ['data', 'number']